# Swift Shake Gesture With An Arrays

Tags: swift, xcode

How do I get the shake gesture to work with my random generator which is set up as an array? Is it possible to do shake gesture with arrays?

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
    }
}

@IBAction func randomActivity(_ sender: Any) {
    let array = [
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have set up some of your code correctly but this is what you could do to tackle your issue ( in the future it's better to post your code though rather than a screenshot ^____* ):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


var activityArray = ["Go For A Walk", "Go For A Jog", "Get Some Coffee", "Debug"]


override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

  //1. Register As 1st Responders
  self.becomeFirstResponder()

}

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Generate A Random Number Between 0 & The Acitivy Array Count
    let randomIndex = RandomInt(min: 0, max: activityArray.count-1)
    print("Lets \(activityArray[randomIndex])")
}


/// Generater A Random Int Between Two Numbers
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - min: Int
///   - max: Int
/// - Returns: Int
func RandomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    if max < min { return min }
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
  }

}
```